# EF Code First. TPT Inheritance and child related entities not loading

Tags: entity-framework-4

I've been with this for a while and didn't find the solution yet. I didn't see anything similar here in SO.

First of all, EF 4.3.1.0 and MVC3

I have a class Component from which two tables inherit: Group and Item. Also a Group can contain a list of Components (which as we know they can be Groups or Items).

Up to that point everything is fine. Now the problem. There is another class: Layout. A Group (and only a Group, not Item nor Component) has a Layout.

The problem is that when I load all the Components hierarchy the Layout object for a Group is always null.

Let me put some pieces of code:

```
public abstract class Component
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public int OrderNum { get; set; }
    public virtual Group ParentGroup { get; set; }
}

[Table("Group")]
public class Group : Component
{
    public virtual IList<Component> Items { get; set; }
    public virtual Layout Layout { get; set; }

    public Group()
    {
        this.Items = new List<Component>();
        Layout = new Layout();
    }
}

public class Layout
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried with and without Lazyloading.

If I include the Layout table in the call to the context it works as long as I retrieve only Groups. If I retrieve also Items it will throw an exception (obviously it can make the relation between Item and Layout).

So if I retrieve all the Components then if the component is a Group I have to do another call to the context to retrieve that exact Group object and then it will come with the Layout. But I consider this way quite inefficient, besides that I'm not going to do that also in the views when I show all the hierarchy.

As far as I can think, as I'm retrieving the entities as Component and the Component does not have Layout, then Layouts are not being loaded for the Groups, even when some of the Components are indeed Groups with Layouts.

**My question is how can I retrieve all the hierarchy like a Component hierarchy and then when I go through it if the current element is a Group to be able to access the Layout after doing a cast of the Component into a Group, instead of retrieving manually from the database.**

Please ask any question if you feel that you need more information about my problem. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: So what exactly is the question? Do you have problem with lazy loading or with eager loading?

Comment: Hi Ladislav, I edited the text, have a look at it, at the end, in bold. Thanks